# How to serve two responses for a single request in Python Flask

Tags: http, flask, response

I have a two step analysis that I serve using Python Flask. First step is fast (done in a second) and important. Second step is not that important (consider it a fine analysis that noone needs immidiately) and it takes minutes. I would like to write code that roughly does this

```
@app.route("/analize_stuff/", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    file = request.files['file']
    result1 = do_first_analysis(file)  # takes a second
    return jsonify(result1.report_form)  # (the first return)

    # takes minutes, hard to compute how long
    result2 = do_slow_unimportant_analysis(result1)
    return  jsonify(result2.report_form)  # (the second return)
```

The problem is that once I hit the first return I have two problems.
(1) The execution stops at the first return (I can use a dirty hack like try, finally)
(2) The client forgets about the request once it gets first return.

What is the right way to tell client "You got the answer to the important question (go and parse the response), but don't drop the connection, I will process less important data and tell you more"?

---

Update
I can return a json like {'res1': result1, 'res2' : result2}. The problem is that I want to first return the most important result that is computed in a second, then later the less important result that is computed in minutes. Not both results after minutes of computation.

So, the only solution I can think of is this. Since my server returns the result to another server, that other server can be set listening. Then I can process the first result, return it. And once I get the second result I can post it to the listening port on the server.

Is this the only solution?

BTW, how does an app on a client's device receives push messages? Does it also open port ffor listening?

Comment: I don´t know how to make exactly u want. But if u put in two routes and call in sequence the second one that is less important, the effect is the same that u want. The user it will receive a message and after it will for second route process.

Comment: @MatheusBrito, good plan. Should they call the second handler every second to see if the processing is done? I can serve them a response to "get my data UUID" with "not ready yet" or "here is your data". But is this optimal?

Answer (score 1):

in python and every programming language you can't return something twice. Return is the end of the function which you return the output.

In python you can return multiple output values like this

```
def myfunc():
   a = 1
   b = 2
   return a,b
x,y = myfunc()
```

In this function x will be assigned to a(1) and y will be assigned to b(2). But in flask, you can't use this method. Because if you add a second argument to a return statement it is a status code.

You can use json responses instead like this:

```
@app.route("/analize_stuff/", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    file = request.files['file']
    result1 = do_first_analysis(file)  # takes a second

    # takes minutes, hard to compute how long
    result2 = do_slow_unimportant_analysis(result1)
    return  jsonify(result1=result1.report_form,result2=result2.report_form),201#Response code
```

Will return you a dictionary with both results.
Alternatively, you can create new routes or take arguments for deciding what to return.

### Update

You can use flask socket-IO for sending realtime data from one server to another and no need to return in a web endpoint.
Here is the documentation:
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You can use a socketio server instead and make a connection and start listening in the other hand. You can check Flask-SocketIO but don't forget to check your gunicorn configurations while publishing the app.

Comment: I will study. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @sixtytrees . Can you please approve my answer?